# error trying to install Postgres on Windows to use with existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I did the following after installing Postgres locally:

```
gem install postgres-pr
```

I changed the database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql 
  encoding: unicode 
  database: typhoon_development 
  pool: 5
```

Then, when I did a rake db:create got:

```
uninitialized constant PostgresPR::Connection::UNIXSocket
Couldn't create database for {"encoding"=>"unicode", "adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"typhoon_development", "p
ool"=>5}
```

I'm doing it locally to mimic the heroku environment.

Comment: Have you tried using `utf-8` instead of `unicode`? Additionally, is Postgres listening to the default port (5432)? Username and password correct? Do they have the required priveleges and the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different gem

Comment: Which gem did you use? I tried postgres-pr on windows (version 0.6.3) and got a NameError: uninitialized constant PostgresPR::Connection::UNIXSocket error. (I was using Ruby 1.9.2).

Comment: I *think* i used pg --- and it worked, but now I am using linux for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide hostname and port number in the config.